# How to arrange sequence range in group by

Tags: sql, group-by, sequence

**Hi all 
i am facing a problem and need a query for that , 
I have a table and data like**

```
----------

seq_id  run_id  mark_Flag 
1         10       A      
2         11       A
3         12       A
4         13       Z
5         14       A
6         15       A  
7         16       Z
8         17       Z
9         18       A
10        19       A
11        20       Z 
----------
```

Now i required the output like

```
seq  runidFrom    runidTo   mark_Flag
1     10             12        A
2     13             13        Z 
3     14             15        A
4     16             17        Z 
5     18             19        A
6     20             20        Z
```

Thanks in advance ....

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! On this site you supposed to show your approach to resolve an issue - so we could say what's wrong with your code. More information in [help] page

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Try this query the main idea is to group by count of previous `Mark_flag` not equal to current

```
SELECT min(run_id),max(run_id),max(mark_Flag)
FROM T as T1
GROUP BY mark_flag,
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T 
         WHERE seq_id<T1.seq_id 
               and 
               mark_flag<>T1.Mark_flag 
)
ORDER BY MIN(seq_id)
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16114/2)</kbd>

This query have to work on any database system but when you post a question please add a tag with your RDBMS (not just <kbd>SQL</kbd>) so a query can be optimized for your data base system.

UPD: Here is the MS SQL version:

```
SELECT min(run_id),max(run_id),max(mark_Flag)
FROM 
(
  Select run_id, mark_flag,seq_id,
    (
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T 
               WHERE seq_id<T1.seq_id 
                     and mark_flag<>T1.Mark_flag 
    ) as group_id
From t as T1
) as T2
GROUP BY mark_flag,group_id
ORDER BY MIN(seq_id)
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/efb96/4)</kbd>

Comment: I'm not sure that all databases allow subqueries in the `group by` statement.  That could easily be fixed by adding it to the `select` and making this a subquery.

Comment: it is showing error Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @pranhat here is [MSSQL server version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/efb96/4)